# Error getting virt-manager to work with LXC

Tags: virt-manager

I'm trying to get virt-manager working for LXC containers in Ubuntu 20.04 beta. I already installed the `lxc` package through `apt`.

```
Unable to connect to libvirt lxc:///.

Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlxcd-sock': No such file or directory

Libvirt URI is: lxc:///

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 956, in _do_open
    self._backend.open(connectauth.creds_dialog, self)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 172, in open
    conn = libvirt.openAuth(self._open_uri,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 104, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlxcd-sock': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure, you have all needed libvirt packages installed.

Install

```
sudo apt install libvirt-daemon-driver-lxc
```

Check

```
sudo apt list libvirt* --installed
```